# Чи є відмінність у вживанні слів "чисельний" і "числовий"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова

Як правильно *чисельний аналіз* чи *числовий аналіз*? На [словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53415/32780.html):

> **Чисельний**. 1. Який стосується **числа**; числовий: *чисельний аналіз*. 2. Кількісний: *чисельна перевага, чисельне зростання населення*.
>
> **Числовий**. Прикм. від число: *числова величина, числові дані, числова послідовність, числові назви, числове розв’язання рівнянь, числове програмне керування.*

Для мене ці слова схожі за значеннями, але хочеться більш детально розібратися. Чому саме чисельний аналіз, чому не числовий аналіз? Чи є за цим якась логіка, чи це просто так усталилось?

Answer (score 2):

За визначеннями словопедій дійсно дуже важко розрізнити значення. Тим паче, що у 1) значенні слова *чисельний* *числовий* наводиться як синонім. 
Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов) також подає обидва прикметники як синоніми-відповідники російського количественный:

> **Коли́чественный** – кі́лькісний, *числови́й, чисе́льний*, (варв.) квантитати́вний.

У довіднику ["Культура професійного мовлення: Навчальний посібник для студентів вищих навчальних закладів"](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=6WHrCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=bffortdWEn&sig=1eYOBK7KQKW7ufsXsFkt2VwOgSM&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6-sj4kqDaAhUFyaYKHS24DV4Q6AEIhgEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false) Лісового М. І. знаходимо таке тлумачення:

> **Чисельний** – виражений у якій-небудь кількості, кількісний (чисельний
>   склад).
>   **Числовий** – пов'язаний з числом, за допомогою якого
>    передається кількість одиниць, подвійність чи множинність предметів.

Виглядає так, ніби суворого розрізнення немає.

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8) є стаття про математичні методи. Там перевага надається використанню сполучення чисельний метод (цікаво, що з наголосом на першому складі), хоча подекуди виникає і числовий у тому ж значенні.
Цікавим є [термінологічне вживання](http://xn--r1a3b.xn--b1amgblet.xn--j1amh/index.php?title=%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85) цих паронімів у сфері інформатики. Числовий - тип даних, а операції, що над ними проводяться, - чисельні.